# GRASS 6.4.6 shell doesn´t work on Macbook High Sierra with QGIS 2.14

Tags: macos, shell, qgis, macos-high-sierra, grass

I have a question about the use the `GRASS 6.4.6` (2016) Plugin that comes with the QGIS 2.14.21-Essen version. I installed the software on a Macbook that runs on High Sierra 10.13.3 and haven´t used any other versions of either GRASS or QGIS prior to the current one. As I prefer to use the long term stable version of QGIS, I was thinking to stick to the 2.14 version. As far as I know, this one only allows you to use the GRASS 6 version.

The problem is that the use of the GRASS shell doesn´t seem to work. As you can see on the picture, it doesn´t allow you to type anything at all. It just shows a white box.

Does anyone else experience this problem, or does anyone have an idea what I could do to fix it?

**grass_6_shell**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck on this exact problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I was lucky to have a Windows computer as an alternative. I think it has/had to do with the development of QGIS 3, which might be worth trying by now.